# How to return focus to Word document from where the macro opened Excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim oRng As Word.Range
Dim arrExcelValues()
Dim i As Long
Dim x As Long

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Risk Words.xlsx")
objExcel.Visible = False

i = 1
x = 0

Do Until objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value = ""
   ReDim Preserve arrExcelValues(x)
   arrExcelValues(x) = objExcel.Cells(i, 1).Value
   i = i + 1
   x = x + 1
Loop
objExcel.Quit

For i = 0 To UBound(arrExcelValues)
    Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range
    Options.DefaultHighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
    With oRng.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = arrExcelValues(i)
        .MatchWholeWord = True
        .Replacement.Highlight = True
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
Next
End Sub
```

Wrote this code to pick words from the Excel file and check it in the Word file to see if they are present and highlight them. However, it does not seem to work from Set oRng = ActiveDocument.Range. Although, if I put a MsgBox before that, it does show the values picked up from the Excel and store in the array.

Comment: "It does not seem to work": what exactly doesn't work? Does the code throw any error? If so: what error and at which line? Enter debug mode and try querying  "ActiveDocument" right before the "Set oRng. .." statement

Comment: In addition to what @user3598756 asks: WHERE is the CommandButton located that triggers this code?

Comment: If you're calling the macro from the Word document, then setting the `oRng` before you open Excel file might help.
Or you could put `Word.Application.Activate` before trying to write to Word

Comment: Yeah I just made a document and spreadsheet that seem to match your description and the code worked fine. If you could post what it is that isn't working and what exactly you do to reproduce the problem that would help!

Comment: Hi Dani El, it worked like a charm! Thank you so much. Could you please copy and paste your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're calling the macro from the Word document, then setting the `oRng` before you open Excel file might help. Or you could put `Word.Application.Activate` before trying to write to Word